# render a html file for a specific URI then gives error in tomcat 8.0

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlets

a html file render without specify URI in java file then its run correctly

when a html file render in specific URI by **IF** block then it gives error.

but if I send message by PrintWriter Object then in **IF** block it Works correctly

**Error**

```
    *HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception
type Exception report
message Servlet execution threw an exception
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    com.javaHello.App.doGet(App.java:22)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    com.javaHello.App.doGet(App.java:22)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    com.javaHello.App.doGet(App.java:22)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    com.javaHello.App.doGet(App.java:22)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    com.javaHello.App.doGet(App.java:22)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    com.javaHello.App.doGet(App.java:22)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    com.javaHello.App.doGet(App.java:22)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    com.javaHello.App.doGet(App.java:22)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    com.javaHello.App.doGet(App.java:22)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)*
```

**App.java**

```
 public class App extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String Url= String.valueOf(req.getRequestURI());
        RequestDispatcher rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("docs/myPage.html");
        System.out.println(Url);
        if (Url.equals("/service/reg")){
            rd.include(req, res);
        }else {
            rd.include(req, res);
            System.out.println("server is hit");
        }
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.javaHello.App</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

**myPage.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>static Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Registration  Page</h2>

<form method="get" action="/register">
    <table>
        <tableBody>
            <tr>
                <td>UserName : </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="UserName"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password : </td>
                <td><input type="password" name="Password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="register" name="btnReg"></td>
                <td><input type="reset" value="clear" name="btnClr"></td>
            </tr>
        </tableBody>
    </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Project Structure**

[image]

Comment: try changing rd.include(req, res); to rd.forward(req, res);

Comment: if use forward(req,res);   same error occure #Anand Rockzz

Comment: Could you show your projects folder structure please..

Comment: Looks like some other external configuration issue, can you try running the sample which I've written - https://github.com/anandchakru/ServletIntro